# How to make a change event to a textbox based on a condition in jquery

Tags: jquery

im trying to hightlight a textbox if its clicked inside,but its not picking up the change.

```
<input type="password"  id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="........" style="">

$(document).ready(function () {

            if ($('#txtPassword').click(function () {
                $("#txtPassword").css({ "background-color": "red" });
            }));


        });
```

its a pretty simple code but when i click on the textbox its supposed to change its colour,but it doesnt change.Im not using an onclick() method because i need to do it with jquery.Any suggestions?

Comment: Ur code work perfect . https://jsfiddle.net/shree/f5kxarer/

Comment: Yeah thats what i dont understand as to why its not firing

Comment: May be you forget to include js library ?

Comment: let me check that

Answer (score 0):

`.click` assigns an event listener that is triggered when that event occurs. You shouldn't wrap it in a condition. *If* the textbox isn't clicked, the event simply won't fire.

Technically, the condition shouldn't break your code, it just doesn't make semantic sense. In `if(condition) { body }`, the condition will always be evaluated, to see if  it yields a truthy value, so your event listener will always be set, and will always yield a jQuery object, so you shoud always reach the body of your if statement, which you haven't included any.

This is enough to set the background color to red when the textbox is clicked:

```
$('#txtPassword').click(function () {
   $("#txtPassword").css({ "background-color": "red" });
});
```

Note that this event fires on `click` only. If you want the textbox to be red whenever it gains `focus`, i.e. by tabbing into the textbox, you should set the color on `focus`:

```
$('#txtPassword').focus(function () {
   $("#txtPassword").css({ "background-color": "red" });
});
```

... and reset it on `blur` if that's what you're interested in.

Of course, if you only want to change a style based on focus state, you can simpy achieve that using the `:focus` pseudo selector in CSS:

```
#txtPassword:focus { background-color: red }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you are expecting:

```
  $("input.address_field").on('click', function(){  
     $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');
 });
```